# Declaratively wrap array elements with objects in MongoDB/Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a legacy DB structure, where every array element is wrapped as a key-value:

```
"field" : [
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456789012345678901234")
  }, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456789012345678901235")
  }
]
```

Can I model it in Java without introducing an intermediate object?
E.g. something like

```
@SomeMagicAnnotation("_id")
List<ObjectId> field;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia will want a class structure to map because of those documents.  You can, however, use `@PostLoad` to iterate over that array and create a new array with only those `ObjectId` values.  Once you have this new array, you can put it back in the `DBObject` with `put("field", newArray)`.  This will make it look like a bare array of `ObjectID` values to Morphia who can then map it to your `List<ObjectID>`.

Comment: An interesting alternative to the wrapper class. Maybe less obvious, IMO. Thanks for the answer!